# Outlook Web Access insert custom hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-web-access

I would like the ability to add a hyperlink to a signature file, however when I do it only gives me the option to paste the URL.  It does not give me the option to name the link.  How do I accomplish this.  Can I use html to add a hyperlink manually?

instead of this

```
http:/www.blah.com/&key=GHDNFNJ34N2JSDNJFSKDJ43J2K3N4JK/abunch/of/directories/index.html
```

I want to see this

```
Click for Coverage Form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you can just highlight the custom text you want to create the hyperlink for and then click the "Insert Hyperlink" icon to give it the URL address.

[image]

Comment: Suppose you want to name that hyperlink so the receiver doesn't see a 300 character url.  I edited my answer to make this more clear

Comment: You can name the hyperlink whatever you want.  Just make sure you highlight the text you want turned into a hyperlink before clicking the "Insert Hyperlink" icon.  In my example above, the hyperlink is named "My Website", but the URL is "http://google.com" (or could just as easily be a 300 character URL)

Comment: Your comment helped tremendously.